# What is the difference between Socket timeout and Query timeout in hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, sockets, jdbc

I have a task to implement timeout for database calls. We use hibernate framework. I have configured below timeouts in hibernate.xml file.

Hibernate.xml

- Connection timeout -> hibernate.c3p0.timeout : 44000
- Socket Read
  timeout -> hibernate.connection.oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout: 60000

I would like to know the difference between socket read timeout and query timeout. Any help in configuring query timeout would be better.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

When you use and close a connection, hibernate keep it for reuse later in time...

When the `Connection timeout` is reached the connection is closed and if the pool is not full, another connection is opened.

The query timeout is the max time allowed to a query to run before being forcefully closed (long queries)

If you have a problem socket timeout problem you should set a `validationQuery` like

`select 1 from dual` for Oracle databases
`select 1` for MySQL databases

Comment: We use Hibernate criteria to query the database. How can i set query(criteria) timeout in hibernate.xml file?

Comment: You set it on each query, like so: criteria.setTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS);